# How to run single function in to a number of times in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, dataframe

I tried to run simple function n times by using the code below:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame()

def repeat_fun(times, f, args):
    for i in range(times): f(args)

def f(x):
    g = np.random.normal(0, 1, 32)
    mm = np.random.normal(491.22, 128.23, 32)
    x = 491.22+(0.557*(mm -491.22))+(g*128.23*(np.sqrt(1-0.557**2)))
    print x
repeat_fun(2,f,df)
```

But I want the result column-wise with respect to run times. The function above gives the result in one array types.Can anyone help me to figure-out this problem.

Comment: Your function is taking an argument but never using its value before assigning a new value to it - why would you do this?

Comment: Please give [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what you mean, but I assume you want the results of `f` to be stored as columns in a dataframe. If thats's the case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()

def repeat_fun(times, f, args):
    for i in range(times): f(i,args)

def f(iteration,df):
    g = np.random.normal(0, 1, 32)
    mm = np.random.normal(491.22, 128.23, 32)
    x = 491.22+(0.557*(mm -491.22))+(g*128.23*(np.sqrt(1-0.557**2)))
    df[iteration] = x

repeat_fun(2,f,df)
```

Run this and look at/print the contents of df and see if that helps.